# How can you fingerprint a Django web app?

Tags: fingerprinting, web-scanners, django

In order to better protect my Django web app, I want to reduce the leakage of information that could help an attacker profile my application. If you were an attacker, what would you look at to identify a Django web app?

From [OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-project-automated-threats-to-web-applications/assets/oats/EN/OAT-004_Fingerprinting), I know that this kind of probing...

> typically examines HTTP header names and values, session identifier
> names and formats, contents of error page messages, URL path case
> sensitivity, URL path patterns, file extensions, and whether
> software-specific files and directories exist

I've taken care of the obvious one:

- renaming the default `/admin` page to something much less guess/brute force-able.

Using some automated tools/browser extensions, I was not able to identify the framework I was using, and I cannot identify any distinct file extensions, url patterns, or cookies.

Is there a distinguishable feature/header/pattern with Django apps?

Comment: well, you're kind of in charge of what you app sends in headers, aren't you? I mean, HTTP headers are plaintext, when you ask your browser to show you the headers, does anything strike you as specific?

Comment: @MarcusMüller to be fair, it is not always obvious what ends up being framework-specific.

Comment: @schroeder true, but I'll argue the risk Kyle's mitigating is more that someone figures out specifics about his application than that this thing is running atop of Django, which really is one of the biggest frameworks there is and hopefully well-supplied with security updates. You wouldn't be stopped by a lack of fingerprintability if an attempt at exploitation was about as resource-intense...

Comment: @MarcusMüller sure, and I, too, question the ultimate value of obfuscating the framework used, but that's the question, and it's valid.

Comment: @schroeder what I want to say: avoiding finger printing might be a step towards reducing the load that automated attackers might put on your system, even if they don't actually succeed at abusing it. However, it's hardly a security measure (being solely based on security by obscurity). If you're spending a lot of (mental) resources on avoiding to be recognized, you might not be focusing on the right thing.

Comment: @schroeder ah, timing collision on our comments. I agree, the question's valid!

Comment: I hope no one is focusing too much of their time on obscuring the framework over other more robust security. There could be some value in that an attacker with a (hypothetical,) known vulnerability for Django 3.1.2 would have an easier day if he could identify apps running the framework, no?

Comment: Just making sure all the boxes are checked: have you tried WhatWeb and Wappalyzer (browser addon)?

Comment: @Saustin yeah, those 2 are the 'automated tools' I mentioned in the question. They mostly returned info that I could already glean from Chrome dev tools, in a more pretty format.